# How Do I Model a Fact that is Related to Many Dimensions in my Data Warehouse Design

Tags: many-to-many, data-warehouse

I am building a data warehouse for property management.  The first fact table is ServiceTicket_FACT where we will keep track of the number of service tickets across various dimensions.  One of the dimensions is "Property."  When a tenant reports an issue with their unit, a Service Ticket is generated and, among other things, the property in which the tenant lives is associated with the Service Ticket.  In the majority of cases, a Service Ticket is associated to one and only one Property.  However, there are cases a single Service Ticket is associated to many properties.  For example, the property management company may create one Service Ticket to "Inspect Basement" and they assign this one service ticket to five different properties.

Suppose I have ServiceTicketID 1 and it is associated to PropertyIDs 1, 2, and 3.  If I use a bridge table between Service Tickets and Properties then my one Service Ticket will appear to be 3 service tickets.  If I use an "allocation factor" on my bridge table (for example, PropertyID 1 is 33%, PropertyID 2 is 33%, and PropertyID 3 is 34%, then I get fractional service tickets, which doesn't make sense in the real world.  I would need my reports to show that PropertyID 1 had one service ticket, PropertyID 2 had one service ticket, and PropertyID 3 had one service ticket.

How do I model this in my data warehouse?

Comment: If you want to report these as separate service tickets then create separate fact records, each linked to an individual property

Comment: What analytical questions will your model need to answer?